# Html table with few headers and but one cell spreading on entire row

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table with multiple headers, but i have some scenario where I wish to display a single row, with some text centered in the middle.
this is the attempt:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Telephone</th>
  <th>Telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>No values</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I want is No values cell to be on the entire row and text centered.

Comment: did you mean colspan? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: <tr><td colspan="3">No values</td></tr>

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `colspan` attribute

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">No values</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```